# Can't distribute appclip from XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-appclips

I am creating an app which includes an AppClip. I added the Clip in the build phases (as an Embed AppClip), I use everywhere the good BundleID (either the parent app, or the clip) but when I'm archiving the app, and then I distribute it, i'm still getting this error: **IDEFoundation.AssociatedAppClipIdentifiersFilterErrors error 1** I can't figure why this happen, it's the first Clip I do and deploy so it's all new to me.

Comment: Not sure what that error means but I've made a guide: https://github.com/aheze/AppClipQuickStart

Comment: Actually, i can't submit my app to the appstore connect since i have added the AppClip.. @aheze